# Regex to Change Particular Text to CAPS

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a string like this

```
<PolygonHotSpot PostBackValue="M001" AlternateText="small letters" Coordinates="93, 57, 94" />
```

I need rejex to capture only AlternateText value and change it into CAPS like **SMALL LETTERS**

So the string would be

```
<PolygonHotSpot PostBackValue="M001" AlternateText="SMALL LETTERS" Coordinates="93, 57, 94" />
```

I've treied something but none of them worked.

Comment: I can't test anything right now, but look at the `MatchEvaluator` parameter of `Replace` and see if you can feed in something like `m => m.Value.ToUpper()`

Answer (score 0):

People here are not fans of using regex to parse html. With all the warnings about doing so, here's the general method for regex. Someone else may give you the Dom parser alternative (in which case use it).

- Use this regex: `AlternateText="([^"]*)`. It captures the text you want to Group 1.
- In the replacement, use a lambda to replace Group 1 with what you need.

I could help you with C#, but don't know the ASP.NET syntax. Someone else can give you the details. :)

**Explanation**

- `[^"]` is a negative character class that matches any character that is not a double quote
- the `*` quantifier matches zero or more of those
- the `(parentheses)` capture that match to Group 1